# Loop through list in AppleScript and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, applescript

I’m currently using AppleScript to automate some tasks in Safari. I have below code, which is supposed to set the value of the text box ‘ownerValue’ to the item from the loop. Whenever I execute the code, nothing happens.

```
set countryList to {"BR", "CN"}
repeat with country in countryList
    
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        tell document 1
            do JavaScript "document.getElementById('ownerValue').value = country"
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat
```

When I replace the country in the loop to the actual country value, e.g. “BR”, it then inserts the text into the text field.

```
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        tell document 1
            do JavaScript "document.getElementById('ownerValue').value = ‘BR'"
        end tell
    end tell
```

It also seems that AppleScript doesn’t recognise country as an item from the loop, since country is not in green.

[image: It also seems that AppleScript doesn’t recognise country as an item from the loop, since country is not in green.]

Any ideas on how I can fix this so I can let AppleScript loop through the values in countryList?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will resolve the issue of the  *variable* not being treated as a *variable*:

```applescript
set countryList to {"BR", "CN"}
repeat with country in countryList
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        tell document 1
            do JavaScript "document.getElementById('ownerValue').value = '" & country & "';"
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat
```

However, you may have another issue here, in that you are looping while inputing the *value* of a new *variable* into the same input field. In other words the **JavaScript** *command* as written is going to first input **BR** and immediately overwrite it with **CN**.

Note that the color of `country` in the code above is not showing as *green*, however, here is a clipped screenshot from **Script Editor** and you see it's *green*.

[image]

---

To address the comment:

> Could you please explain why it was previously not treated as a variable but now is?

When mixing two languages, i.e. **AppleScript** and **JavaScript** in this use case, and passing an **AppleScript** *variable* to **JavaScript**, you need to build out the **JavaScript** *command* using concatenation so the *value* of the *variable* is expanded.

In your code it was being treated as a fixed *value* as **JavaScript** has no way of knowing it was an **AppleScript** *variable*, hence *concatenation*, i.e. `& ... &`. In **AppleScript**, `&` is the *concatenation character*.

Comment: Thanks, this actually worked :) Could you please explain why it was previously not treated as a variable but now is?

Regarding the loop: It’s actually only part of the code - I had shortened it to make it easier to read. But thanks for highlighting this, too :)

Comment: @greasyfries, RE: "Could you please explain why it was previously not treated as a variable but now is?" --  Please see "To address the comment:" section in the updated answer. Thanks.